# Will Apache load and process .htaccess file during every request

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, httpd

... or there is an optimization which reduces operation cost to single `stat()` call in case file is unmodified?

Please provide a reference link of some kind.

Answer (score 3):

Just read the docs yourself, it's listed in there:

> Also, the .htaccess file is loaded every time a document is requested.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html